# Implementing the map function with a list of indices

Tags: list, haskell, map-function

I want to implement the map function for specific indices only, like this:

`mapFor :: (a -> a) -> [Int] -> [a] -> [a]`

An example would look like this.

`mapFor (+10) [0,2] [1,2,3,4] == [11,2,13,4]`

Comment: What's the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: in your example, the first index you are changing is the 0'th index, which is right at the front of the list.  You could probably find a way to do that operation on the first element of the list, and then use recursion to do the same thing on the rest of the list.  Explicit recursion is NOT going to be the most efficient way to do this, but if you are new enough to haskell to ask this question, you should almost always do it the simple way first.

Comment: @arrowd my Attempt was to use list comprehension, which got me to map just the indexed terms, but wont show the remainder of the list. 
`mapFor f is xs = map f [xs!!a | a <- is]` In the case above it would just return `[11,13]`

Comment: @BorisKurova your approach with list comprehension is ok, but then I would suggest you need pairs of (index,value): `[ <something with is, f, i, and v> | (i,v) <- zip [(0::Int)..] xs ]`. This is probably the simplest approach. Not the best if you are looking for the max efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @cornuz I figured it out.

`` mapFor f is xs = [if (i `elem` is) then f v else v | (i,v) <- zip [0..] xs] ``

If you see any issues, please let me know so I can fix them.

Comment: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Play with the data to find the pattern, to fulfill the given requirements:

```
mapFor (+1) [0,2] [100,200,300,400] == [101,200,301,400] ==

  =   {   [ 100,    200,    300,    400 ]    -- values
          [ 0,        1,      2,      3 ]    -- indices
          [ 0, 2 ]                       }   -- places
     --------------------------------------
  =    (100+1) : { [200,    300,    400 ]    -- values
                   [  1,      2,      3 ]    -- indices
                   [  2 ]                }   -- places
     --------------------------------------
  =    (100+1) : 200 :   { [300,    400 ]    -- values
                           [  2,      3 ]    -- indices
                           [  2 ]        }   -- places
     --------------------------------------
  =    (100+1) : 200 : (300+1) : { [400 ]    -- values
                                   [  3 ]    -- indices
                                   []    }   -- places
     --------------------------------------
   =
       ........
```

where `{ ... }` signifies our transformation.

Then, *generalize!* -- by replacing concrete data with symbolic variables, and you've got yourself a working -- recursive -- code.

```
mapFor op places values = g [0..] places values
  where
  g (i:is) (p:ps) (v:vs)         -- most general case
   | i == p      =  ....
   | otherwise   =  ....
  g  _     []      _   =   ....  -- base case
  ......                         -- more corner cases, if any
```

Make sure you *exhaust all possibilities* with your patterns.